# Functional notation usage for arbitrary relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question about questionable notation used in a homework assignment.

The assignment defines a relation *f* := { (0,1), (1,3), (2,1) }. It then asks to "show" this is a function. IMO strictly (i.e. Bourbaki) speaking it is not but so be it. The intention is clear.

It further asks to calculate *f*[2], *f*(2), *f*<sup>-1</sup>[1], *f*<sup>-1</sup>(1), ...

It is understood that the author uses Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs, the natural numbers as *n* = {0, ..., *n*-1} and that *f*<sup>-1</sup> is the inverse relation
*f*<sup>-1</sup> = { (1,0), (3,1), (1,2) }, which is obviously not a function.

So my question is: **what could** *f*<sup>-1</sup>(.) **possibly mean** for the non-functional relation *f*<sup>-1</sup>? It is sometimes used as a sloppy alternative notation for *f*<sup>-1</sup>[.] but it is obvious from the question that the author makes a strict distinction between [.] and (.). And that whatever (.) is supposed to mean, its definition should generalize Euler's notation (.) for functions.

Comment: As it's from a homework assignment, the logical person to ask is the person who assigned the homework.

Comment: What does it mean : "IMO strictly (i.e. Bourbaki) speaking it is not (a function)…" ?

Comment: Bourbaki definition of function is : a triplet (X, Y, f) where f is a subset of X x Y satisfying the functional axioms. f is then referred to as the "graph" of the function.

Comment: (continued). A looser definition of is that any relation satisfying the functional axioms is a function. However, this does not specify the codomain of the function (Y) and the question: "is this function surjective" is meaningless.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For reasons I won't get into it is not possible to contact the person.

Answer (score 1):

We have the well-known set-theoretic definition of *relation* (a set of pairs, for a binary one) and the definition of *function*, i.e. a relation which is "functional".

For a relation $R$ we define its [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) :

> for a binary relation is the relation that occurs when the order of the elements is switched in the relation.

The converse relation of a function always exist; if it is a function, we say that the function is *invertible*, in which case the converse relation is the inverse function.

The symbol for the converse of $R$ is not very standard; we have $\breve{R}$, but sometimes $R^{-1}$ is used.

Having said that, for $f = \{ (0,1), (1,3), (2,1) \}$, we have that $f^{-1} =  \{ (1,0), (3,1), (1,2) \}$, in which case $f^{-1}(1) = \{ 0, 2 \}$.

---

*Added after the comments exchange*.

Ref. to Herbert Enderton, [Elements of set theory (Academic Press, 1977)](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA46), page 46.

Definitions :

> The *inverse* [most commonly applied to functions, sometimes are applied to relations] of $F$ is the set $F^{-1} = \{ (u,v) \mid (v,u) \in F \}$
>
> The *restriction* of $F$ to $A$ is the set $F \restriction A = \{ (u,v) \mid (u,v) \in F \text { and } u \in A \}$.
>
> The *image* of $A$ *under* $F$ is the set $F[A] = \text {Range}(F \restriction A) = \{ v \mid (\exists u \in A) ((u,v) \in F) \}$.

An interesting example follows :

> Let $F = \{ (\emptyset, a), ( \{ \emptyset \}, b) \}$. Observe that $F$ is a function. We have $F^{-1} = \{ (a, \emptyset), (b, \{ \emptyset \}) \}$ which is a function iff $a \ne b$.
>
> The restriction of $F$ to $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$, but $F \restriction \{ \emptyset \} = \{ ( \emptyset , a) \}$.
>
> > Consequently, $F[ \{ \emptyset \} ] = \{ a \}$, in contrast to the fact that $F( \{ \emptyset \})= b$.

Now we can try to answer the problem above, considering your statement that for the author : "the natural numbers are $n = \{ 0, \ldots, n-1 \}$."

We have that $f(2)=1$ (an element) while $f[2]=f( \{ 0,1 \} ) = \{ 1,3 \}$ (a set).

In the same way, if we have to be consistent with the notation, we must have :

> $f^{-1}[1]=f^{-1}[ \{ 0 \}]= \emptyset$, because there are no pairs $(0,x)$ in $f^{-1}$,

while $f^{-1}(1)= \{ 0,2 \}$, because $f^{-1}$ is not a function.

Comment: It's only notation... The author is very specific (elsewhere) that $R[x] := \overleftarrow {R}(x) := \{ y\mid (x,y) \in R \}$. Also specific that when $R$ is a function $R(x) := $ the value that function, the unique $y$ where $(x,y) \in R$. Also very mindful that $f[2]$ and $f(2)$ are not the same thing. And that $f^{-1}[1]$ and $f^{-1}(1)$ are not the same thing, whatever the latter may be.

Comment: I believe the correct answer to the homework question is: "the author is not qualified to teach set theory and should be teaching gym instead" but doubt that will get me a good grade.

Comment: I'm with you until the last sentence $f^{-1}(1) = \{0, 2\}$. If for an arbitrary relation R you define $R(x) := \{y \mid (x,y) \in R\}$ then indeed the aforementioned statement is true. However, since $f$ itself is a relation this would imply that $f(1) = \{3\}$ rather than $3$, which would make Euler turn in his grave.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a function f is f$^{-1}$ when the inverse of f exists.
The inverse of a relation R is R$^{-1}$ = { (x,y) : yRx }.
The set extensions of a function f are f[A] = { f(x) : x in A }
and f$^{-1}$[A] = { x : f(x) in A }.

Comment: Downvoted for consistenly [not using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/how-to-deal-with-users-that-just-wont-use-mathjax).